# How to properly display a product within a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, fractions

I have product inside a fraction, like this:

```
\[
\phi_n(t)=\frac{t^n-1}{\prod_{\substack{
    d \mid n,\\
    d<n.}} \phi_d(t)}
\]
```

And that places the "limits" of the product on it's side, not behind, like it would normally do if it were not inside a fraction, like this

```
\[
\prod_{\substack{
    d \mid n,\\
    d<n.}} \phi_d(t)
\]
```

Is there a way to make it display the limits behind the product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `\limits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\[
\phi_n(t)=\frac{t^n-1}{\prod\limits_{\substack{
    d \mid n,\\
    d<n.}} \phi_d(t)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason is that fractions started in display style have their numerator and denominator in text style (where limits are set on the side rather than above and below); `\limits` is the correct answer; but probably I'd try a different way to express the identity.